# NullPointerException in File Upload by tomahawk

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, tomahawk

I want to upload an Excel file to a JBoss Server with JSF, so I used Tomahawk.

Here is the view:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions" prefix="x"%>

<h:form id="MF" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <x:inputFileUpload id="fileupload" value="#{dataentryctl.minvoice}" storage="file" required="false" />
    <h:commandButton id="Submit" type="button" action="#{invoiceentryctl.PersistData}" value="save" 
        onclick="revalidateF12();submitForm()" onkeydown="keyDownEvents(this)" />
</h:form>
```

Here is the controller/model:

```
package panaceaFACweb.FACCtlbean;

import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class dataentryctl {

    private UploadedFile minvoice;

    public UploadedFile getMinvoice() {
        return minvoice;
    }

    public void setMinvoice(UploadedFile minvoice) {
        this.minvoice = minvoice;
    }

    public String PersistData() {
        load();
        return null;
    }

    public void load() {
        ParseXLS parseXls = new ParseXLS();
        try {
            InputStream input = minvoice.getInputStream();          
            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following JARs:

- tomahawk-1.1.9.jar
- commons-el-1.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.2-javadoc.jar
- commons-io-1.4.jar

Other JARs related to JSF are already there. Other JSP pages work fine.

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the line `InputStream input = minvoice.getInputStream();`.

Comment: Format your code in a code block.

Comment: Why are you using MyFaces extensions taglib instead of Tomahawk taglib? Replace `http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions` by `http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk` and `<x:inputFileUpload>` by `<t:inputFileUpload>`, just to be sure. What exactly are those JS onclick/onkeydown functions on the submit button doing? Remove them and retry, just to be sure that they didn't do wrong stuff. Do you have MyFaces extensions filter configured in `web.xml`?

Comment: Yes Mr Mukul , I had changed to http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk and <t:inputFileUpload> . Now I am getting "http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" Not found.
Error :(. I had Added the Jar and i had also Configured web.xml .

Comment: MY WEB.xml Changes.<filter>
<filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param><description> ... </description><param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
<param-value>100m</param-value></init-param> <init-param>
<description> ...</description>
<param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
<param-value>100k</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

Comment: <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>